# Carry output issue during VHDL ALU synthesis

Tags: compiler-construction, vhdl, addition, synthesis, alu

I'm trying to build and synthesize an ALU in VHDL but I get a problem as soon as I synthesize.
I'd like my ALU to have a op-code for adding my two N-bits inputs and a carry that may be set by an input or by a sum that was calculated earlier.
The part of the code I'm interested in is as follow:

```
process (a, b, op) -- a and b are n bits input en op is the op-code
    case op is
        when "011" => -- add a + b + c (with c as carry)
            y <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b) + c; -- y is the N-bit output
...
end process;

process (clk)
   if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
       if (op = "011" and (to_integer(a)+to_integer(b)+to_integer(c)) > (2**N)) then --basically I'm testing if there is an overflow during the calculation
           c <= '1';
       elsif (op = "011" and (to_integer(a)+to_integer(b)+to_integer(c)) < ((2**N)+1))
           c <= '0';
...
end process;
```

I'm not sure if the code will work here because I didn't define the signal types, but basically it comes down to what I've written above.
The problem with this is that when I simulate my VHDL with an appropriate testbench, it works as it should but when I synthesize this code and simulate the synthesized code with the same testbench, it doesn't work properly because then somehow the first process is repeated again even if a, b or op didn't change. So when the outcome of the sum has a carry, the calculation is done again with this new carry and the outcome is incremented by one even if a, b or op aren't changed!

Later on I found this article saying [that the sensitivity list is "ignored" by the compiler](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.nl/2010/04/process-sensitivity-list-vs-synthesis.html) how thinks he knows the program better than you and makes its own sensitivity list. If this is true, I guest the compiler adds clk in the sensitivity list of the first process so the calculation is ran on every clk period when the op = "011".

My question comes now: what can I do about this problem so that the calculation is run once and that the carry is changed after it?

Kind regards

Comment: Stop writing code.  Draw a picture first.  Code your picture.  Did you intend to connect carry out to carry in?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say `I'd like my ALU to have a op-code for adding my two N-bits inputs and a carry that may be set by an input or by a sum that was calculated earlier.` It seems you are confused between `carryin` and `carryout`. Generally these are two separate things. Why do you want to add the carry generated by the adder (`carryout`) to the input numbers again ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are a few problems with your code. I'll try to suggest some improvements, and then show a possible way for calculating the carry flag:

1. Make a distinction between the carry in and carry out signals. Use communicative names for your signals, such as `carry_in` and `carry_out`. This will remove much of the confusion.
2. Define a constant or an enumerated type for your ALU operations. For instance:

   ```
   subtype opcode_type is std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
   constant ADC: opcode_type := "011";  -- ADC: add with carry
   ```
3. Finally, if you are using VHDL 2008, you can generate your carry out using an aggregate as the assignment target:

   ```
   (carry_out, y) <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b) + carry_in;
   ```

Your code would end up looking like this:

```
process (all)
    case op is
        when ADC => -- add a + b + c (with c as carry)
            (carry_out, y) <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b) + carry_in;
    ...
end process;

process (clk)
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        carry_flag <= carry_out;
    ...
end process;
```